# Auto transition in Jira issue in integration with Swarm

Tags: jira, transition, jira-plugin, swarm

I have integration of Jira and Swarm where the code is sent for review and I would like to find any opportunity for auto transition of status in JIRA issue from Open/In Progress to In Review as soon as code review in Swarm starts. And when this code review is done and the task in Swarm is closed I would like to have in JIRA linked issue auto transition to status Resolved. It seems to me that the solution should be easy but I cannot find any ready plugin or solution for this problem. Please could anybody help me?